# Filtering in multiple child nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Is it possible to filter in several child nodes at the same time?
Based on the example below, I would like the xslt to check whether the "blue attribute" value is not exists.

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
    <item>
        <Date>2023-02-19</Date>
        <Cars>Ford</Cars>
        <SellTarget>A4+</SellTarget>
        <Time>10:40:09</Time>
        <avg>19.3464027998</avg>
        <product>
            <defaultmarkers>
                <Markers>
                    <Marker remarks=""/>
                    <Marker remarks=""/>
                    <Marker remarks=""/>
                    <Marker remarks=""/>
                    <Marker remarks="Blue"/>
                    <Marker remarks=""/>
                    <Marker remarks=""/>
                    <Marker remarks=""/>
                    <Marker remarks=""/>
                </Markers>
            </defaultmarkers>
        </product>
        <firstmarkers/>
    </item>
    <item>
        <Date>2023-02-19</Date>
        <Cars>Ford</Cars>
        <SellTarget>A4+</SellTarget>
        <Time>11:21:56</Time>
        <avg>32.7150023474</avg>
        <product>
            <defaultmarkers/>
        </product>
        <firstmarkers>
            <Markers>
                <Marker remarks=""/>
                <Marker remarks=""/>
                <Marker remarks=""/>
                <Marker remarks=""/>
                <Marker remarks="blue   "/>
                <Marker remarks=""/>
                <Marker remarks=""/>
                <Marker remarks=""/>
                <Marker remarks=""/>
            </Markers>
        </firstmarkers>
    </item>
    <item>
        <Date>2023-02-19</Date>
        <Cars>Ford</Cars>
        <SellTarget>A4+</SellTarget>
        <Time>19:01:27</Time>
        <avg>554.0289810087</avg>
        <product>
            <defaultmarkers>
                <Markers>
                    <Marker remarks=""/>
                    <Marker remarks=""/>
                    <Marker remarks="Yellow"/>
                    <Marker remarks=""/>
                    <Marker remarks="Blue"/>
                    <Marker remarks=""/>
                    <Marker remarks=""/>
                    <Marker remarks=""/>
                    <Marker remarks=""/>
                </Markers>
            </defaultmarkers>
        </product>
        <firstmarkers>
            <Markers>
                <Marker remarks=""/>
                <Marker remarks=""/>
                <Marker remarks=""/>
                <Marker remarks=""/>
                <Marker remarks="blue"/>
                <Marker remarks=""/>
                <Marker remarks=""/>
                <Marker remarks=""/>
                <Marker remarks=""/>
            </Markers>
        </firstmarkers>
    </item>
    <item>
        <Date>2023-02-20</Date>
        <Cars>Opel</Cars>
        <SellTarget>A4+</SellTarget>
        <Time>15:01:02</Time>
        <avg>65.6303001034</avg>
        <product>
            <defaultmarkers>
                <Markers>
                    <Marker remarks=""/>
                    <Marker remarks=""/>
                    <Marker remarks=""/>
                    <Marker remarks=""/>
                    <Marker remarks="Yellow"/>
                    <Marker remarks=""/>
                    <Marker remarks=""/>
                    <Marker remarks="Green"/>
                    <Marker remarks=""/>
                </Markers>
            </defaultmarkers>
        </product>
        <firstmarkers/>        
    </item>
    <item>
        <Date>2023-02-21</Date>
        <Cars>Opel</Cars>
        <SellTarget>A4+</SellTarget>
        <Time>02:00:00</Time>
        <avg>1.2954721559</avg>
        <product>
            <defaultmarkers/>            
        </product>
        <firstmarkers>
            <Markers>
                <Marker remarks=""/>
                <Marker remarks=""/>
                <Marker remarks=""/>
                <Marker remarks=""/>
                <Marker remarks="Green"/>
                <Marker remarks=""/>
                <Marker remarks=""/>
                <Marker remarks=""/>
                <Marker remarks=""/>
            </Markers>
        </firstmarkers>
    </item>
</data>
```

MY XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" 
    xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" 
    xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" 
    xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" 
    xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
    
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    
    <xsl:variable name="lowercase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'" />
    <xsl:variable name="uppercase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'" />
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        
        <Workbook>
            <Styles>
                <Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal">
                    <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
                    <Borders/>
                    <Font ss:FontName="Calibri" x:CharSet="238" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="11"
                        ss:Color="#000000"/>
                    <Interior/>
                    <NumberFormat/>
                    <Protection/>
                </Style>
                <Style ss:ID="s63" ss:Name="mydefault">
                    <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" ss:Vertical="Center"/>
                    <Font ss:FontName="Verdana"/>
                </Style>
                <Style ss:ID="s62" ss:Name="Normal_">
                    <Font ss:FontName="Verdana" ss:Bold="1"/>
                    <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" ss:Vertical="Center"/>
                </Style>
                <Style ss:ID="s67" ss:Parent="s63">
                    <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" ss:Vertical="Center"/>
                    <NumberFormat ss:Format="yyyy\.mm\.dd"/>
                </Style>
                <Style ss:ID="s69" ss:Parent="s63">
                    <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Left" ss:Vertical="Center"/>
                    <Font ss:FontName="Verdana"/>
                </Style>
                <Style ss:ID="s72">
                    <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" ss:Vertical="Center"/>
                    <NumberFormat ss:Format="[$-F400]h:mm:ss\ AM/PM"/>
                </Style>
            </Styles>
            
            <Worksheet ss:Name="Report">
                
                <Table>
                    <Column ss:Width="63.75"/>
                    <Column ss:Width="31.5"/>
                    <Column ss:Width="61.5"/>
                    <Column ss:Width="50.25"/>
                    <Column ss:Width="87.75"/>
                    <Column ss:Width="56.25"/>
                    
                    <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" >
                        <!-- Date -->
                        <Cell ss:StyleID="s62">
                            <Data ss:Type="String">Date</Data>
                        </Cell>
                        <!-- Cars -->
                        <Cell ss:StyleID="s62">
                            <Data ss:Type="String">Cars</Data>
                        </Cell>
                        <!-- SellTarget -->
                        <Cell ss:StyleID="s62">
                            <Data ss:Type="String">SellTarget</Data>
                        </Cell>
                        <!-- Time -->
                        <Cell ss:StyleID="s62">
                            <Data ss:Type="String">Time</Data>
                        </Cell>
                        <!-- avg -->
                        <Cell ss:StyleID="s62">
                            <Data ss:Type="String">avg</Data>
                        </Cell>
                    </Row>
                    
                    <xsl:for-each select="data/item[not(product/defaultmarkers/Markers/Marker[contains(translate(@remarks, $uppercase, $lowercase), 'blue')])]">

                        <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
                            <!-- Date -->
                            <Cell ss:StyleID="s67">
                                <Data ss:Type="String"> 
                                    <xsl:value-of select="Date"/>
                                </Data>
                            </Cell>
                            <!-- Cars -->
                            <Cell ss:StyleID="s67">
                                <Data ss:Type="String">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="Cars"/>
                                </Data>
                            </Cell>
                            <!-- SellTarget -->
                            <Cell ss:StyleID="s67">
                                <Data ss:Type="String">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="SellTarget"/>
                                </Data>
                            </Cell>
                            <!-- Time -->
                            <Cell ss:StyleID="s67">
                                <Data ss:Type="String">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="Time"/>
                                </Data>
                            </Cell>
                            <!-- avg -->
                            <Cell ss:StyleID="s67">
                                <Data ss:Type="String">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="avg"/>
                                </Data>
                            </Cell>
                        </Row>
                    </xsl:for-each>                    
                </Table>
            </Worksheet>
        </Workbook>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I tried "or" and "and" at "for-each", but they shouldn't be checked at the same time, but neither of them gave the result.

Is it possible the check at both nodes:

here:
/data/item/product/defaultmarkers/Markers/Marker/@remarks

and here:
/data/item/firstmarkers/Markers/Marker/@remarks

and just show that "item" where no "blue" value at the remarks attribute?

MY result:

```
Date    Cars    SellTarget  Time    avg
2023-02-19  Ford    A4+ 11:21:56    32.7150023474
2023-02-20  Opel    A4+ 15:01:02    65.6303001034
2023-02-21  Opel    A4+ 02:00:00    1.2954721559
```

Expected result:

```
Date    Cars    SellTarget  Time    avg
2023-02-20  Opel    A4+ 15:01:02    65.6303001034
2023-02-21  Opel    A4+ 02:00:00    1.2954721559
```

Thank you, Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<xsl:for-each select="item[not(product/defaultmarkers/Markers/Marker[contains(translate(@remarks, $uppercase, $lowercase), 'blue')] or firstmarkers/Markers/Marker[contains(translate(@remarks, $uppercase, $lowercase), 'blue')])]">
```

---

If there are no other Markers, you could shorten it to:

```
<xsl:for-each select="item[not(.//Marker[contains(translate(@remarks, $uppercase, $lowercase), 'blue')])]">
```

Comment: I had the change "item" to "data/item", but looks good for the first look, thank you.

Comment: That's because my template matches `"/data"`. I find that more convenient - esp. for long paths such as these.

Comment: thanks for the help, and Happy Holidays, regards